# ActivityPluginBinding is returning null

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to run a AlertDialog in my flutter plugin. So I need the Activity context. I tried using the Application context. However, I was greeted with this fine error and learned that I must use the Activity context.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

For some reason when I call getActivity() it always returns null. I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers as to why this is happening. Here is my Plugin class I cleaned it up so it only contains the ActivityAware code. Did I not implement something correctly? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
  private ActivityPluginBinding activityBinding;
  private FlutterPluginBinding flutterBinding;


  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    flutterBinding = flutterPluginBinding;
  }


  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    activityBinding = binding;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromActivity() {
    activityBinding = null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    activityBinding = binding;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
    activityBinding = null;
  }

  // Implementation

  public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return (flutterBinding != null) ? flutterBinding.getApplicationContext() : null;
  }

  public Activity getActivity() {
    return (activityBinding != null) ? activityBinding.getActivity() : null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those objects might have cleared by time they are accessed. You can keep WeakReference to Application context and Activity context and access them later. This way you will avoid memory leak as well.

Something like

```java
private WeakReference<Context> weakApplicationContext;
private WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;
```

and then

```java
  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    weakApplicationContext = new WeakReference<>(flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext());
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    weakActivit = new WeakReference<>(binding.getActivity());
  }
```

Then access them as

```java
public Activity getActivity() {
    return weakActivity.get();
}
```